# ƒ is a monotonic increasing function under two total orders, R and S, of a set A. How are R and S related?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

This is problem #9 from section 7.4 of Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes. Intuitively, it seems to me that either R=S, or S is R's converse. However, I don't see how one would approach proving this. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify whether this is correct and if so, where to begin with proving it.

Comment: Is $A$ a finite set?

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer A is an arbitrary set.

Comment: I don't think they have to be anyway related. For example, if $f$ is the identity of $A$, then $f$ preserves any binary relation whatever; in particular, it is monotonic increasing (and decreasing) for any order relation...

Comment: @amrsa After considering it again, I believe you are correct unless I'm misinterpreting the problem in the book. I guess that I assumed there must have been more to the problem. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: By "increasing", do you mean "strictly increasing" ? Or could it be, say, constant ?

Answer (score 0):

If by increasing you mean "strictly increasing", i.e. $x R y \rightarrow f(x) S f(y)$, where $R, S$ are strict order relations, then :

$R$ embeds into $S$, i.e. the map $f$ defines a copy of the order $R$ on $A$, using the set $Im(f)$ and the order induced by $S$ on this set.

Proof : Take two points $a, b$ in $Im(f)$. Then there exist $c,d$ in $A$ such that $f(c) = a$ and $f(d) = b$. Then, $a S b$ if and only if $c R d$. Moreover, $f$ is injective since the orders are total.

However, you do not necessarily have equality of the orders. For instance : $R$ is the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$, $S$ is the usual one on $\mathbb{N} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, and $0$ is bigger than everyone else. Then, if $f(x) = x+1$, the map $f$ is increasing from $(\mathbb{N}, R)$ to $(\mathbb{N}, S)$. But the orders are not equal.

Comment: Hi @FiMePr, thank you for the answer. I think the way you interpreted the question is likely how the author originally intended it to be phrased, but the wording in the book (at least how I read it) asks a more ambiguous question. "Let R and S be strict simple [total] orderings of A and let ƒ be an increasing function on both <A,R> and <A,S>. How are R and S related?" Here an increasing function is one such that Dom(ƒ) = A, Ran(ƒ)⊆A, and xRy → ƒ(x)Rƒ(y). I think that in this setup we only have xRy → ƒ(x)Rƒ(y) and xSy → ƒ(x)Sƒ(y) to work with.

Comment: But then, with this interpretation, $f$ could be the identity, no ? In which case, it adds no information....

Comment: Since Suppes defines an increasing function as one from  <A,R> to the same <A,R>, there's apparently no reason why ƒ should affect S. I'm guessing that there was either a mistake in the phrasing, or perhaps it was meant as a trick question to test students' understanding of the definitions?

Comment: With all due respect, if Suppes only considers the cases where the order onthe domain and the order on the codomain are equal, then he misses many interesting cases.

Comment: It does seem like an odd pedagogical decision, but to be fair, Suppes does at least discuss order-preserving bijections between arbitrary sets with total orders, but it's not directly connected to his treatment of increasing functions.